# Custom field to checkout page in opencart 2

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I m trying to add a custom field to checkout page. The problem is I am getting "Undefined index: my_field" during 6th step (confirming the order). I am using version 2.1.0.1

I have added a textarea to payment_method.tpl

```
<textarea name="my_field"></textarea>
```

I also added these lines to payment method controller (payment_method.php)

```
if (isset($this->request->post['my_field'])) {
    $data['my_field'] = $this->request->post['my_field'];
} else {
    $data['my_field'] = '';
}
```

And added this to my confirm.php which is under controller directory

```
$order_data['my_field'] = $this->request->post['my_field'];
```

I added this line to order.php for updating the database also

```
$this->db->escape($data['my_field']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured it out by
Changing this

```
$order_data['my_field'] = $this->request->post['my_field'];
```

to

```
$order_data['my_field'] = $this->session->data['my_field'];
```

I also added this line to payment_method.php

```
$this->session->data['my_field'] = strip_tags($this->request->post['my_field']);
```

after this line:

```
$this->session->data['comment'] = strip_tags($this->request->post['comment']);
```